# is there a better way to code for two dependent observables

Tags: rxjs

In the method below I want to call two observables. After the data from first observable (getUnrecoveredGearsExt- a http req) is returned I want to pass the data to the second observable (createUpdate- persist to indexDB). Is there a cleaner way to achieve this maybe using some of the  rxjs operators. thanks

Note: after the successful completion of the second observable I want to return the data from the first Observable. The use case is get data from the backend and store locally in indexDB and if successful return data or error

```
public getAndUpdateUnrecoveredGears(cfr: string, maxResults?: number, excludeTripid?: string) : Observable<GearSet[]> { 

    return Observable.create((observer) => { 

      this.getUnrecoveredGearsExt(cfr,maxResults,excludeTripid).subscribe(
        (gears: GearSet[]) => {
          this.createUpdate(gears).subscribe(
            () => {
              observer.next(gears);
              observer.complete();
            },
            (error) => {
              observer.error(error);
            }
          );
        },

        (error) => {
          observer.error(error);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Having nested `.subscribe()` methods is an anti-pattern of RxJS and can cause many issues. So it's a strong signal of when you need to use operators. Fortunately, there is one which simplifies your code.

```
public getAndUpdateUnrecoveredGears(cfr: string, maxResults?: number, excludeTripid?: string) : Observable<GearSet[]> { 
  return this.getUnrecoveredGearsExt(cfr,maxResults,excludeTripid).pipe(
    concatMap((gears:GearSet[])=>this.createUpdate(gears))
  );
}
```

Because we're dealing with HTTP requests, they'll emit one value then complete. For this, we can use `concatMap()`. This operator will wait until `getUnrecoveredGearsExt()` completes, and then will subscribe to `createUpdate()` using the value emitted from `getUnrecoveredGearsExt()`. The operator will then emit any values coming from this "inner observable".

Assuming `createUpdate()` is also an HTTP request, it will automatically send a complete signal after emitting the response.

Comment: thanks digclo thats a nice solution. Unfortuately I was not clear in my description. I need to return the data from the first observable after successful completion of the second observable. I have updated the problem description. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works for me. The final issue was how to pass the previous result 'gears' out as a final result. This is achieved by using the combineLatest to pass the two results to the next map operator, which can then pass gears out.

```
public getAndUpdateUnrecoveredGearsAlt2(cfr: string, maxResults?: number, excludeTripid?: string): Observable<GearSet[]> {
    return this.getUnrecoveredGearsExt(cfr,maxResults,excludeTripid).pipe(
      switchMap((gears: GearSet[]) => { return combineLatest(this.createUpdate(gears),of(gears));}),
      map(([temp, gears]) => gears )      
    );
  }
```